# Outputting PDF with Django as attachment and reload

Tags: django, pdf-generation, reload

I´m using django to generate a pdf and return the response as an attachment in the view.

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=somefilename.pdf'
```

Similar to the way described in the doc [(http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/#write-your-view](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/#write-your-view))

What is the best way to reload the page?

This didn´t work out (the form triggers the pdf generation):

```
$('#the_form').submit(function(){
  location.reload();
});
```

Thanks a lot,
Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reload. Instead create a view which is the target of the form. The view generates the PDF in a directory that is delivered from the real web server and then sends the user to the appropriated URL, where he can download the file (use HttpResponseRedirect).

Comment: Thanks Martin. This is a good alternative. Is it still possible to return the PDF as attachment?

Comment: I decided to implement the approach suggested by Martin.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the forms target to the view that generates the pdf. Below I included some pros and cons for this approach vs the approach suggested by Martin (to write files to a directory the world can read)

Pros:

- You can do authentication or special billing or whatever
- Every request will generate a new PDF (unless you explicitly cache it)

Cons:

- Every request will generate a new PDF
- Memory usage
- You have to stream a file from Django

--

Another solution would be to use the X-SendFile header of your webserver. Do a google search for instructions for your particular server. The general idea is that your view gives the webserver a path to a file which the webserver will then read directly from disk and return to the user. You can probably "force download" even these files, have a look at the documentation for your webserver on how to do it.

Comment: I´m sending the form target to the view that is generating the pdf and get the attachment as a response.

<code>def some_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=somefilename.pdf'
 ...
    return response
</code>
But the page won´t reload after the response is returned.

Comment: Aha. I see. Well, when you do stuff on form submit with javascript, that will run before the form is actually submitted, so you cannot do any reloading or redirects there. The easiest solution I can come up with is to call window.setTimeout(function() { window.location = '/your/url/' }, timeout_in_milliseconds) in the submit handler, but it is really a rather ugly hack.